# How do i test json object from php web servicec is empty?

Tags: php, android, json

After an http request, sometimes my application may return an empty object, like:
({})
but when i test if it's empty i don't get the result from the else.

```
JSONObject user = new JSONObject(object);
                            Log.i("",String.valueOf(user.length()));
                            if(user.length()!=0) {
                                String name = user.getString("login");
                                String passs=user.getString("password");
                                Toast.makeText(a_log.this, "Bienvenu : "+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(a_log.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("LOGINEE",user.getInt("id"));
                                startActivity(intent);                                }

                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(a_log.this, "Vous n'avez pas de compte Veuillez vous inscrire ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Thread.sleep(2500);
                                tv_l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
```

Comment: What happening when using `user.length()` ?

Comment: Nothing this appear : System.out: pool-2-thread-1 calls detatch()

Answer (score 1):

test your if condition as
...

if(user.has(login) )

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

> How do i test JSONObject from PHP WebService is empty?

With `JSONObject.length()` also use [JSONObject.has(key name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)) and [JSONObject.isNull(key name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull(java.lang.String)) to check is `JSONObject` contains key without `null`:

```
 if(user.length()!=0) {
   if(user.has("login") && user.isNull("login")){

   }
   ....
 }
```

Comment: But user.isNull is for checkinf if the key to login is null not the opposite ?

Comment: @HamzaAmrani: Yes `isNull` is to check value associated with `key`. in your case both is required so first check if key is present in JSONobject then check if key have a valid value before parsing